# Server to server communication in iis with http

Tags: http, iis, websocket

I have two servers running in iis on different computers and they need to communicate with each other. Because of firewalls etc http is the only real option. It's bidirectional communication, not just request/response. Web sockets would be good, but the spec for that isn't finished so I'm wondering if there are any other options I should look at?

Comment: Can you not just configure a socket-based program to communicate over port 80?

Comment: No because the servers also have to serve HTML on port 80.

Comment: Got it, what web socket implementation did you have in mind to deploy in IIS?  Sounds like that is the way to go given the situation.

Comment: I don't know yet. I'm running on appharbor so I don't have full control over the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would spend a few minutes thinking about wether my communication could actually be done using request response, a lot of times you can convert your communication into request response. HTTP is really very request response based so you kind of have to hack around it using various [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) techniques like long polling. If you have control over both ends of the communication then there is no reason not to use web sockets even if the standard isn't settled upon. So long as you agree with yourself how it should be implemented complying with the final standard isn't important.

Comment: I'm wondering if there are any other options that I should be looking at instead of web sockets. How did people solve this issue when web sockets wasn't around?